# JQuery-UI error after installing via NPM (Meteor application)

Tags: jquery-ui, meteor, npm

I have a Meteor application (1.4.1) and have just installed the `jquery-ui` npm package (1.12.1). I also have jquery installed via npm (3.1.0).

I am receiving the following error in the browser console:

> Error: Cannot read property 'sortable' of undefined TypeError: Cannot
>   read property 'sortable' of undefined

This refers to this block in my code:

```
( function($, undefined ) {
    $.widget( "ui.sortable", $.ui.sortable, {
        ...
    });
}(jQuery) );
```

I have tried with/without importing the jquery-ui package at the top of the page:
import 'jquery-ui';

but still no joy. I have also viewed the source on the page and I cannot see jquery-ui anywhere, however, when I list the npm modules in the terminal, jquery-ui is listed. Any ideas what the issue is?

Comment: I can't say I'm entirely sure because I don't use jQuery UI, but you might have to set a type.  See types in the docs http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/. Maybe try it outside Meteor so you can test if the problem is with Meteor or jQuery UI

Answer (score 0):

This is not directly an answer to your question, but certainly a solution: just use the already-wrapped meteor package instead of installing the npm package directly (https://atmospherejs.com/mizzao/jquery-ui):

```
meteor add mizzao:jquery-ui
```

Comment: Appreciate the answer, but as the preferred way is towards NPM and away from Atmosphere packaes, it would be ideal to have a solution based on using the NPM package.